# how to save gplot output to file in matlab?

Tags: matlab, graphics

Can you guys suggest way to save/output gplot to file. I am still trying to figure things out with Matlab. Thanks.

```
A=[0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0;
1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0;
1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0;
1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0;
1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1;
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1;
0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0;
0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1;
0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0];

coords=[0 0;
.5 0;
1 0;
0 .5;
.5 .5;
1 .5;
0 1;
.5 1;
1 1];

gplot(A,coords)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to output the figure to a file:

```
 saveas(fig_handle, 'filename','bmp')
```

or

```
 print('-dbmp',fig_handle)
```

the trick is before calling gplot you should get a figure handle

```
 fig_handle = figure
```

Comment: you can also use gcf (the handle of the current figure) saveas(gcf, 'filename','bmp');